# Automated build visual studio 2008

Tags: tfs

I have vs2008.i have 10 projects in it TFS. is there any way i can automate there build process one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can have TFS build multiple projects by specifying them in the SolutionToBuild item group: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399127(VS.90).aspx

You may have to adjust your workspace mapping (in the build definition dialog) to ensure that all projects are available to the team build.